# How do can we refresh a UITableView on apple tvos?

Tags: uitableview, tvos, apple-tv, uirefreshcontrol

Since UIRefreshcontrol does not work on tvos, I am looking for alternate solution to refreshing a UITableView. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you show an example of the tvOS application where you will need this feature?